# In place vector "abs" warning: operation may be undefined?

Tags: c, gcc

```
static inline void vect_abs(float *srcdst, int n)
{
    while (n-- > 0)
       *(srcdst++) = fabsf( (*srcdst) );
}
```

Why is this code giving the `warning: operation on ‘srcdst’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`?

Comment: Read up on sequence points.

Comment: `=` operator doesn't introduce a sequence point; you're reading & writing to the same object without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: What value you are expecting `srcdst` to be when calling `fabsf( (*srcdst) );` ? The previous one or the incremented one?

Comment: OK, first `*srcdst = fabsf( *srcdst );`, then `srcdst++;`.

Comment: I think the canonical question on this topic is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge, agree, that should be the one.